# Store data in List or form library

Tags: infopath

I recently worked on a solution where user would fill out a form and data are stored on a separate list. But noticed that list template is just out of box for edit.

I need to build some logic on the form when they edit. Should I customized the List Template form? Or should I use "form Library" and store data in the form library that way I dont have re-do the form. Just realize that I can't user "Form Library" because I am also saving (aka attaching) files to the custom list.

Anyone?

Comment: You are asking how to do something you have never specified.

Answer (score 1):

> Just realize that I can't user "Form Library" because I am also saving
>   (aka attaching) files to the custom list

You can also attach files to form or document library... and they will be indexed/searchable in contrast to list attachment. Also it is possible to save into sharepoint lists from form libraries...

You can find useful:

- Table 3. Comparing form library and list templates in msdn article [Building SharePoint Applications with InfoPath 2010 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961896.aspx#IP14BuildingSPApplicationsPT1_BestPracticesforIPSPApps)
- [Comparing SharePoint List and Form Library Forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/22/comparing-list-and-form-library-forms.aspx)
- [Nik Patel. InfoPath 2010 and SharePoint 2010 – List Forms vs Library Forms](http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/infopath-2010-and-sharepoint-2010-list-forms-vs-library-forms/)